# Scheduling several alarms with WakefulIntentService

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to schedule several alarms to publish posts to twitter. I am not sure of the usage, because i am getting a NullPointerException.

i have a list with posts and i would like to post them to twitter, so this is what i did.
In the scheduleAlarms method of WakefulIntentService class i have a for loop iterating over the posts List and adding a post object to the putExtra method:

```
public static void scheduleAlarms(AlarmListener listener, Context ctxt,
        boolean force) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = ctxt.getSharedPreferences(NAME, 0);
    long lastAlarm = prefs.getLong(LAST_ALARM, 0);

    if (lastAlarm == 0
            || force
            || (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastAlarm && System
                    .currentTimeMillis() - lastAlarm > listener.getMaxAge())) {
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) ctxt
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        for (Iterator<Post> iterator = AlarmActivity.posts.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            Post post = (Post) iterator.next();

            Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, AlarmReceiver.class);
            i.putExtra("post", post);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt,
                    (int) post.getId(), i, 0);
            listener.scheduleAlarms(mgr, pi, ctxt);
        }

    }
}
```

Then in my AppService doWakefulWork method i get the Parcelable post object but i am getting a nullpointerexception:

```
@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("AppService", "I'm awake! I'm awake! (yawn)");
    Post post = intent.getParcelableExtra("post");
    System.out.println("- " + post.getPost());
}
```

Is this the right way of doing what i want to achieve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please examine the Java stack trace associated with your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Hello CommonsWare, the NullPointerException states that intent.getParcelableExtra("post") is null.

Comment: I do not really know how to setup several alarms in a List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the NullPointerException states that intent.getParcelableExtra("post") is null.

My guess is that your `BroadcastReceiver` is not forwarding along your `post` extra to the service as part of its call to `sendWakefulWork()`.

> Is this the right way of doing what i want to achieve?

Probably not, as you will only send one post, ignoring all the rest, and you will not even do that correctly if the user powers off or reboots their device.

Use *one* scheduled alarm with *one* `PendingIntent`. Since your posts need to be in a persistent data store, have the `WakefulIntentService` load the posts to send from the data store. Eliminate all extras from the `PendingIntent`, as they are no longer needed and cannot readily be reconstituted in case of a power-off or reboot event.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try your suggestions

Comment: Just one more question. How/where in the WakefulIntentService  do i load  the posts from the List?

Comment: @pindleskin: "How/where in the WakefulIntentService do i load the posts from the List?" -- as I wrote, "since your posts need to be in a persistent data store, have the `WakefulIntentService` load the posts to send from the data store".

Comment: Ok, got it, i.e. from the shared preferences. Now the only issue is that i cannot publish the posts all in a row, there must be a 15 minutes gap between them.

Comment: It seems i cannot make it work. Works great for single alarms, but i am not able to achieve my needs.

Comment: @pindleskin Were you able to solve the problem? If so could you post your solution?

Comment: @pindleskin please it will be helpful  if you can share your solution