# How to set two different WakefulIntentService AlarmListeners?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using Commonsware's WakefulIntentService (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) to trigger a periodic job in my Android application (updating a cache of images). So far so good, but I want to add a different WakefulIntentService, to do a different job, at a different time interval.

I'm not sure if I can do this and how. At the moment, I'm scheduling an alarm like this:

```
WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(new CacheAlarmListener(), mContext, true);
```

The implementation of CacheAlarmListener is this:

```
@Override
public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager alarmManager, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Context context) {
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
}

@Override
public void sendWakefulWork(Context context) {
    WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, CacheRefreshService.class);
}
```

Looking through the source code, the [getListener(Context)](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/wakeful/AlarmReceiver.java#L56)  method from `AlarmReceiver` seems to find and trigger a single AlarmListener. Am I wrong, or is there another way to schedule an alarm or setting a different PendingIntent?

Basically, I would like to be able to register a new, separate `AlarmListener`, or at least be able to figure out which `WakefulIntentService` to send the work to, in the `sendWakefulWork(Context)` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704824/scheduling-several-alarms-with-wakefulintentservice?rq=1

Comment: @SaifuddinSarker, it seems to me that the linked question is quite unrelated. The issue there is not being able to set multiple alarms for the same service. I need to be able to trigger two different services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far so good, but I want to add a different WakefulIntentService, to do a different job

You do not need to do that. A single `WakefulIntentService` can do multiple things, based on different `Intent` characteristics (e.g., action strings, extras). Having multiple `WakefulIntentService` implementations in the same project is untested -- and unless somebody can convince me of its necessity, is unsupported.

> the getListener(Context) method from AlarmReceiver seems to find and trigger a single AlarmListener. Am I wrong

No, you are correct.

> is there another way to schedule an alarm or setting a different PendingIntent?

Follow [the "Basic Usage" instructions on the project's README](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful#basic-usage).

> or at least be able to figure out which WakefulIntentService to send the work to

Please only have one `WakefulIntentService`.

> I need to be able to trigger two different services.

Please only have one `WakefulIntentService`.

Comment: Thank you! I wholly agree, a single service is enough, but I see no way to change any `Intent` characteristic without modifying the code of the method WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms(AlarmListener,Context,boolean). Is there another way?

Comment: I can easily add some extras to the `Intent` created inside that method, but I don't want to modify your code if I don't have to. Anyway, thank you very much, and thank you for the great work you are doing.

Comment: @CorneliuDascălu: Please click on the hyperlink in my answer and read that section. It explains how you can use `WakefulIntentService` without `scheduleAlarms()`.

Comment: OK, my mistake. I have already read the README. I was wondering if there is any way to use `scheduleAlarms()` with different `Intent` extras, but I guess there isn't one. I realize that I can do my own implementation that takes care of setting the alarm, I was just trying to avoid that.

Comment: @CorneliuDascălu: "I was wondering if there is any way to use scheduleAlarms() with different Intent extras, but I guess there isn't one" -- well, `scheduleAlarms()` does not itself have anything to do with the `Intent` extras. However, there may not be an easy way for you to distinguish between different scenarios in which `scheduleAlarms()` is called. That's really for simple alarm scenarios, and you have exceeded "simple" :-).

Comment: I have slowly come to realize this :). Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Hi i just want to add i spent most of the Easter weekend getting the basic version of wakeful intent service working, then went to get on to actually implementing multiple alarms and saw the latest version with the schedule alarms stuff in it and started to get depressed that I'd spent all that time for nothing and would have to redo all my alarms. so i just want to confirm, Mark, that if i want to setup multiple alarms it's best to just use your simple/basic version without alarm listener/alarm schedule?

Comment: Oh and by the way, thanks for making this wakeful stuff, it's really helpful

Comment: @RussWheeler: "that if i want to setup multiple alarms it's best to just use your simple/basic version without alarm listener/alarm schedule?" -- probably. My `AlarmListener` is for simple scenarios. "thanks for making this wakeful stuff, it's really helpful" -- you are very welcome!

Comment: One last thing. You say simple scenarios, but is it technically possible to do multiple alarms with AlarmListener? if so i was just wondering how? Would it mean rewriting/adding too the base classes? In which car I'd rather not messes with your main code.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the rapid response to what isn't exactly a recent question

Comment: @RussWheeler: "You say simple scenarios, but is it technically possible to do multiple alarms with AlarmListener?" -- probably not without modifications. "Would it mean rewriting/adding too the base classes?" -- probably.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. Oh, if i ever released what i was working on, what exactly would i have to do under the apache licence (it's all a bit legal/technical for me)

Comment: @RussWheeler: Sorry, but that's outside the scope of StackOverflow. There is plenty of material online explaining how to apply various open source licenses.

Comment: Pretty sure there are scenarios in which I would need multiple WakefulIntentServices. Right now I want two different tasks to occur at different time intervals, how would I accomplish this with just one WakefulIntentService?

Comment: @lne: Have only one `WakefulIntentService`. Have two alarm events set up with `AlarmManager` with different `Intent` extras. Use an `if()` statement based upon those extras to branch to the appropriate portion of code inside of `doWakefulWork()`. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: @CommonsWare How would I pass an Intent + extras? WakefulIntentService.scheduleAlarms() seems not accept pendingintents in its arguments? I'm somewhat confused.

Comment: @lne: Follow the Basic Usage instructions and schedule your own alarms: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful#basic-usage